# How to collect the array data?

Tags: mysql, arrays, count, group-by

I have a mysql code that needs to be improved because of my limited knowledge. I am new in php-mysql.I have data arrays at my DB and I want to show data such as:

```
Date             Model        Qty         Name
2010-08-23       boo          2          Steve
2010-08-24       boo          1          Steve
2010-08-25       boo          2          David
2010-08-25       blob         1          Steve
```

I have tried using this code, but the results is not like what I wanted.

```
"SELECT id, DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date,
                  A.Model, COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty,
                  B.name
                  FROM inspection_report AS A
                  LEFT JOIN Employee AS B
                  ON A.NIK=B.NIK
                  GROUP BY A.Model, B.name, A.Inspection_datetime"
results:
Date             Model        Qty         Name
2010-08-23       boo          1          Steve
2010-08-23       boo          1          Steve
2010-08-24       boo          1          Steve
2010-08-25       boo          1          David
2010-08-25       boo          1          David
2010-08-25       blob         1          Steve
```

How do I do to resolve this problem?

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inspection_report` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Model` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
          `Serial_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
          `Lot_no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
          `Line` char(5) NOT NULL,
          `Shift` char(1) NOT NULL,
          `Inspection_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
          `Range_sampling` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
          `NIK` int(5) NOT NULL,
          `Class` char(1) NOT NULL,
          `Status` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE KEY `Model` (`Model`,`Serial_number`,`Lot_no`,`Line`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
      `NIK` char(5) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`NIK`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You've shown us what you want, and a query that doesn't work--making it useless to us.  We need to see the existing table structure to start massaging it into what you like, assuming at all possible...

Comment: i have posted my table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date,
                  A.Model, COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty,
                  B.name
                  FROM inspection_report AS A
                  LEFT JOIN Employee AS B
                  ON A.NIK=B.NIK
                  GROUP BY Date,B.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT Date(i.Inspection_datetime) InspectionDate, 
            i.model, 
            e.name,
            Count(*) Qty
     FROM inspection_report i, Employee e
     WHERE i.nik = e.nik
     GROUP BY Date(i.Inspection_datetime), i.model, e.name
```